# Why the one chart overlaps another?

Tags: anychart

I try to draw two linear charts in one canvas and see only the part of one of charts. It looks like one chart overwrites another. What am I doing wrong?

Example here: https://playground.anychart.com/FOA9wGJV/2

Answer (score 1):

solved.
I should use two different scales to display different charts

https://playground.anychart.com/FOA9wGJV/3